# How to add a thumbnail Image for an encrypted image?

Tags: macos, cocoa

I Encrypted an image by using [AES](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Advanced_Encryption_Standard) algorithm. Encryption and Decryption works well. Now the thumbnail of the image is the default image.

[image]

But I want something that looks useful for the user. like this image.

[image]

I have searched a lot but I can find only the quicklook for the document based applications. How can I add thumbnail for jpeg, png or tiff images ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you know the path to the file when you create it and you have the icon images in your project, so then just use the NSWorkspace method **setIcon:forFile:options:**.